# How to paste vaues from excel sheet to table and store it in state in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, events, event-handling

I have created a table in react and I have to paste there values from Excel sheet and store them in a state. I have tried **onPaste and onInput** event but It's storing only last value of the sheet into the state.

```
function App() {
  const [label, setlabel] = useState({ labels: ["Lat [deg]", "Long [deg]"] });
  const [inputvalue, setinputvalue] = useState({
    inputs: [
      { "Lat [deg]": "", "Long [deg]": "" },
      { "Lat [deg]": "", "Long [deg]": "" },
    ],
  });

  const handlePaste = (index, elm, e, i) => {
    return parse(e);
  };

  const handlePaste1 = (index, elm, e, i) => {
    const newList4 = inputvalue.inputs.map((item, i) => {
      if (index === i) {
        const updatedItem = {
          ...item,
          [elm]: e.target.value,
        };
        console.log(updatedItem);
        return updatedItem;
      }
      return item;
    });
    console.log("newList4", newList4);

    setinputvalue((prevData) => ({
      ...prevData,
      inputs: newList4,
    }));

    console.log("Input Value", inputvalue);
  };
  return (
    <table>
      <tr className="text-center">
        {label.labels.map((elm, ind) => {
          return (
            <th
              style={{
                width: "150px",
                border: "1px solid black",
                backgroundColor: labelcolor.labelcolors[ind].color,
              }}
            >
              {elm}
            </th>
          );
        })}
      </tr>
      {inputValues.inputs.map((res, index) => {
        return (
          <tr key={index}>
            {label.labels.map((elm, i) => {
              return (
                <td
                  style={{
                    width: "150px",
                    minHeight: "30px",
                    border: "1px solid black",
                    borderRadius: "0px",
                    wordWrap: "break-word",
                  }}
                >
                  <input
                    onInput={(e) => {
                      handlePaste1(index, elm, e, i);
                    }}
                    onPaste={(e) => {
                      handlePaste(index, elm, e, i);
                    }}
                    type="textbox"
                    className="text-center inputtextbox"
                  />
                </td>
              );
            })}
          </tr>
        );
      })}
    </table>
  );
}

export default App;
```

In the handlePaste1 function, I'm setting states in different elements i.e Lat [deg] and Long [deg]. But I'm getting only last value in the inputValue state.

This is the input:-

[image]

So here input is
1        2
3        4

```
//The value in inputValue state I want:-

inputs: [
          { "Lat [deg]": "1", "Long [deg]": "2" },
          { "Lat [deg]": "3", "Long [deg]": "4" },
        ],

//The value in inputValue state I'm getting:-

inputs: [
          { "Lat [deg]": "", "Long [deg]": "" },
          { "Lat [deg]": "", "Long [deg]": "4" },
        ],
```

**Codesandbox link:-**
[Click here for live code](https://codesandbox.io/s/elastic-flower-z7gq4?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: Please do try to update your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible Code Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). We can't help fix code if we can't see what it's doing.

Comment: Yep! I updated it! I submitted the question without code  by miskae!

Comment: Have you tried the `onChange` handler?

Comment: Yup. Didn't work. Actually on Pasting I'm getting the values in the desired table cells but I'm not getting all of these values inside the state. The state is storing value of last cell only.

Comment: Interesting, the `onChange` worked for me when pasting into an input. What is `inputValues` that you are mapping in your code snippet? I don't see it defined anywhere. Think you could try creating a *running* codesandbox that reproduces the issue for us to inspect and live debug in?

Comment: You can see the image of the input I provided. Also at the end I've provided the values I'm getting in state and the values I want in that state

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Issue

Looks like the issue is related to enqueueing multiple state updates within a single render cycle. It seems that each cell that is pasted triggers its own state update, and since each update is starting from the state value from the render cycle the updates were enqueued in, each subsequent update overwrites the previous update. The last update is the one you see, e.g. you see only the fourth cell updated.

## Solution

Convert the `handlePaste1` to use a functional state update so it is updating from the previous state, as opposed to the state from the previous render cycle.

```
const handlePaste1 = (index, elm, e, i) => {
  setinputvalue((inputvalue) => ({
    ...inputvalue,
    inputs: inputvalue.inputs.map((item, i) =>
      index === i
        ? {
            ...item,
            [elm]: e.target.value
          }
        : item
    )
  }));
};
```

[image: Edit how-to-paste-vaues-from-excel-sheet-to-table-and-store-it-in-state-in-react(fork)]

Comment: Are you pasting the values one by one in each cell?

Comment: @AnkitJaishwal Yes. Are you trying to paste them differently?

Comment: Yes. All at once!

Comment: @AnkitJaishwal Ok, I think I see what was happening, got the copy/paste of multiple cells working in a fork from your codesandbox. Updated my answer and included an explanation.

Comment: Yes Working! Thank You so much!